# Showing variable in a pop-up window

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a small 2D game and I want to print a message when it's finished. The code is in Python and I used both Pygame and Tkinter for 2D graphic.
When the game is finished it shows the message below:

```
messagebox.showinfo('Finish','Mouse ate all cheese slices.\nPolicies saved to file.')
```

I have a variable called `steps` and I need to show it in that window but it raise an error when I tried it like this:

```
messagebox.showinfo('Finish','Mouse ate all cheese slices after {steps}.\nPolicies saved to file.')
```

Update: Using f-string solved the problem:

```
messagebox.showinfo('Finish',f'Mouse ate all cheese slices after {steps}.\nPolicies saved to file.')
```

Comment: What is the error? Post the full traceback.  BTW, you need to use *f-string* in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an f string. Your code should look something like this:

`messagebox.showinfo('Finish',f'Mouse ate all cheese slices after {steps}.\nPolicies saved to file.')`

Here's a link to learn more ways to use this sort of formatting:
[Python F-Strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an f-string:

```py
messagebox.showinfo('Finish',f'Mouse ate all cheese slices after {steps}.\nPolicies saved to file.')
```